# How can i show MinimizeBox without MaximizeBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

How can i show the MinimizeBox without the MaximizeBox.

Comment: Not an option.  You can only make it look disabled, MaximizeBox = false.  Not allowing a user to maximize your window is an odd restriction that doesn't jive well with the way people use windows these days.  The taskbar rules.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide them.
The Form has two properties called `MinimizeBox` and `MaximizeBox`, set false which you do not  need.

To stop the form closing, handle the FormClosing event, and set e.Cancel = true; in there and after that, set `WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;`, to minimize the form.